# Auto suggest using AJAX Control Toolkit, pass value to array

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This is for auto suggest using  AJAX Control Toolkit
I am creating a session and passing the value to this page through page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if
            (Session["useremail"] == null) Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        else
            Label8.Text = Session["useremail"].ToString();
    }
```

I want to use the label8.text value in the method below so that I can use that to query the database and give the result(Firstname from user table) from database to the array movies.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {  
        string[] movies = { "Joey", "Joester", "Joker", "Joeic", "Joic", "Shrek II" };

        return (from m in movies where m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select m).Take(count).ToArray();
    }
```

Please tell me how to pass the firstname value from table user to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an AJAX call, using an UpdatePanel, that has your WebService as its endpoint. You can set up an AsyncTrigger as shown in [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) that passes to a code behind which reads the value of the label's text and calls the web service. If you're using MVC, the approach is a bit different. [This may help with that](http://forums.asp.net/t/1361903.aspx/1).